# Node.js ERROR: (node:9748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: json, node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to get a json from "nightmare" in Node.js and then use JSON.parse(), but I'm getting the following error:

> (node:9748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: Unexpected token ☻ in JSON at position 18509

My code:

```
var nightmare = Nightmare()
        .goto('URL') 
        .wait(10000) // Need wait some time
        .evaluate(() => {
            return document.body.innerText;
        })
        .end()
        .then((body) => {
            var data;
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(body);
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            callback(null, data);
        });
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The body is no valid json and you don't handle errors. It's as easy as the error message says.

Comment: This symbol will never be read in json? I can parse ☻ from body?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the JSON is valid or not simply using the JSON.parse function as you are using.

```
function validJSON(str) {
  try {
    // try to parse the JSON
    JSON.parse(str);
  } catch (e) {
    // if not a json
    return false;
  }
  // if it's valid json
  return true;
}
```

It'll check if the string is valid json or not. Now, you can use it with your nightmareJS.

```
const nightmare = Nightmare()
  .goto("URL")
  .wait(10000) // Need wait some time
  .evaluate(() => {
    return document.body.innerText;
  })
  .end()
  .then(body => {
    // if it's a valid json, send it, 
    // otherwise send it as a body object
    const data = validJSON(body) ? body : { body };
    callback(null, data);
  });
```

Now, the error is showing because you said to **catch(e)** and **console.log(e)** the error. Thus it's simply obeying your command.

Since the emoji itself is not a valid json, you have to either make a json from it, or parse it if it was a json **string**.

A valid json object might look like this,

```
{emoji:  "☻"}
```

You see how it's all quoted?